# Provisioning profile

Tags: ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, organizer

I now have an iPhone 5 that I want to use for development.  I try to add provisioning profiles in Organizer but they are greyed out.  Can't the same provisioning profile be used on multiple devices?

When I have Provisioning Profiles selected in Organizer for the new device, I click on the + symbol on the bottom left to add a provisioning profile.  I navigate to the correct location of the profile and as I mention above, they are greyed out. There is no way to add it this way.

Linda

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode organizer after selecting the device you able to find an option "Add to Portal".Then sign in with your valid apple developer account.Then Everything will be configured automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Linda, the same provisioning profile can be used on multiple devices.

In your case, the chances of the provisioning profile being greyed out may be because:

- The device which you are using is not registered under the provisioning profile you are trying.

Provisioning profile binds

- Certificate
- App ID
- UDID of the device.

All the above 4 bind and work together.

Answer (score 0):

provisioning profile can use to multiple device.

Your case because in your provisioning profile not included your iPhone 5 (UDID).

1. Please check in https://developer.apple.com/
2. add your UDID
3. Create New Provisioning Profile
4. Add your Provisioning Profile To XCode
5. Check in Organizer